# I tried to enable compilation after adding a module and when I run the compilation process, I get this error "Class not found in"

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

this is eroor:-

`Fatal error: Class 'Mage_GiftMessage_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /home/brandhype/public_html/granda/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234`

Comment: i installed this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/geoip-currency-store-switcher-free.html, after installation i tried to run compiler and my site down and shows this error in front and backend.

Comment: Could you show what's happening in includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234 +-10 rows

Comment: $afterApplyUpdates = array();
        foreach ($resources as $resName => $resource) {
            if (!$resource->setup) {
                continue;
            }
            $className = __CLASS__;
            if (isset($resource->setup->class)) {
                $className = $resource->setup->getClassName();
            }
            $setupClass = new $className($resName);
            $setupClass->applyUpdates();
            if ($setupClass->getCallAfterApplyAllUpdates()) {
                $afterApplyUpdates[] = $setupClass;
            }
        }

Comment: better upload your file somewhere like http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you recompile and reenable, or just reenable the compiler?

Some modules will not run with compilation. Check with your module developer to find out if this is the case. (Per section rules, Questions about third-party modules are generally off-topic because the scope of functionality and code are not available.)

You often have the choice between running the Kludge compiler which after Magento 1.6.x.x+ optimizations, doesn't really help performance that much, or running a module that makes your site a much friendlier place for your customer.